# Easier Girard's paradox in a circular pure type system (PTS)

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, lambda-calculus

[System U](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_U) is an inconsistent PTS in that one has a term of type $\bot = \forall p\colon \ast \ldotp p$, and such a term is explicitly constructed in Hurkens' [A Simplification of Girard's Paradox](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kw/scans/hurkens95tlca.pdf).

One-sorted circular PTS $\lambda\ast$ ($S = \{\ast \}, A=\{\ast\colon \ast\}, R=\{(\ast,\ast)\}$) (Geuvers' [Logics and Type Systems](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.56.7045&rep=rep1&type=pdf), p.78) is also inconsistent since a term of type $\bot$ in System U can be translated into $\lambda\ast$ by mapping $\ast, \square$ and $\triangle$ to $\ast$.

Is there any easier way to construct a term of type $\bot$ in $\lambda\ast$? Smaller terms, or constructions easier to understand, are appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I feel like most of my posts on mathoverflow and cstheory.stackexchange consist of this answer, but the most perspicuous (in my opinion) proof of inconsistency of U and $*:*$ is a construction by Alexandre Miquel, given in his [phd dissertation](https://www.fing.edu.uy/~amiquel/publis/these.pdf). Tragically, it is in French, so I'll summarize the idea below, and maybe you'll be able to fill in the remainder using his other paper [*lamda-Z: Zermelo's Set Theory as a PTS with 4 Sorts.*](https://www.fing.edu.uy/~amiquel/publis/types04.pdf).

The idea is to build a model of *naive* set theory in $*:*$. The naive theory allows for unrestricted comprehension, and in particular the paradox falls out quite easily. The proof term of $\bot$ itself is longer than in Hurkens' presentation, but I think it's safe to say that the process is at least more straightforward.

The crucial idea is to model a set as a **directed pointed graph**. The point represents the set, the graph contains all the members of the set, and the membership relation is represented by the edges. We rely on the encoding of $\Sigma$ types in the impredicative theories.

A set $S$ is thus an element of

$$\mathrm{Set}=\Sigma (A:*)(x :A)(R:A\rightarrow A\rightarrow *) $$

where the *carrier* is $A$, the base is $x$ and the edge relation is $R$. What's a bit counter-intuitive is that sets are not necessarily well-founded. To get sane notions of equality and membership, we need to define equality as **bisimilarity** $\simeq$ of pointed graphs.

Then it's pretty easy to define membership: $S\in T$ if

- $T = (A, x, R)$
- There is some $y$ with $R\ y\ x$ ($y$ is an element of $x$)
- $S\simeq (A, y, R)$ ($S$ is the "same set" as $y$)

Then we can show:

> For each predicate $P:\mathrm{Set}\rightarrow *$ **that respects bisimilarity** there is a set
>   $$ \{\ x\ |\ P(x)\ \}$$

It's then easy to show that $P(x)=x\notin x$ respects bisimilarity.

Comment: One can construct the type $U := \Pi (X: \Box_2) (X \to X \to \ast) \to X \to \ast$ of the universe and the relation $\mathsf{elt}\colon U \to U \to \ast$ over $U$, and construct arbitrary sets by the axiom schema of separation. By adding $(\Box_3, \Box_2, \Box_2) \in R$ to $\lambda$Z, one has $U \colon \Box_2$, which leads to the inconsistency.

Comment: By mapping $* \mapsto *, \Box_1 \mapsto \Box, \Box_2 \mapsto \Box, \Box_3 \mapsto \triangle$, one can show that System U (and hence $\lambda\ast$) is also inconsistent. The product rule $(\triangle, \Box, \Box)$ corresponds to $(\Box_3, \Box_2, \Box_2)$ in $\lambda$Z.

Comment: I think I understand how this works with * : *, but could you elaborate how this works in System U? I'm assuming that the construction of {x | P x} relies on instantiating A : * with Set itself somehow? Is that not disallowed in System U, since Set : □ and not Set : *? Or do we have A : □ but still R : A -> A -> *?

Comment: @Jules: $\mathrm{Set}$ has type $*$, just like in system F, $\Pi A:*.A$ has type $*$. This is the impredicative nature of system F, which is even more pronounced in system U, since $\Sigma$ types can be expressed. It's surprising that system F is consistent!

Comment: I was worried about the ∗ at the end of R : A -> A -> ∗. What about that one? Doesn't this make Set : □, which means that you can't instantiate A with Set?

Comment: I guess another way to ask the same question is: where exactly does this proof fail for System F?

Comment: @Jules late reply, sorry, I was lazy about digging into this stuff again. As H Koba mentions, in system U $A : \Box$ and not $*$, which allows $\mathrm{Set}$ to be of type $\Box$ and so $A$ may be instantiated by it. You see that you need the 3 levels here, $*:\Box:\bigtriangleup$ with impredicativity at the second level.